# how to get background button with selector drawable in android?

Tags: android, drawable

how to get background button with selector in drawable folder?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_press" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_mati" android:state_selected="false"></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this,
Create button_selector.xml in drawable folder,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_hover" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_hover" android:state_focused="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_hover" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

    </selector>



              <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                />
```

in your java class,

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
```

Comment: how to get background .xml button ?

Comment: can i get background selector in java class?

Comment: getbackgroud? not setbackground